# How to create a UILabel dynamic height and layout anchor constraints?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UILabel that gets updated with text of varying of lengths and is positioned with layout anchor constraints. I am having trouble with getting the correct height. Sometimes the last line is cut off but not always.

defining the label

````
message.textAlignment = .center
message.numberOfLines = 0
message.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = frame.width
message.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
popUpWindow.addSubview(message)

message.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
message.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: POP_UP.SPACING_Y).isActive = true
message.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: POP_UP.EDGE_INSET).isActive = true
message.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -POP_UP.EDGE_INSET).isActive = true
message.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cancel.topAnchor, constant: -POP_UP.SPACING_Y).isActive = true```
````

updating the text. newText varies in length.

```
message.text = newText
message.sizeToFit()
setNeedsLayout()
```

sample input:

```
newText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

[image]

note that "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." is cut off.

(full layout constraints for reference)

```
let layoutGuide = popUpWindow.safeAreaLayoutGuide

popUpWindow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
popUpWindow.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
popUpWindow.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
popUpWindow.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true

imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: POP_UP.EDGE_INSET).isActive = true
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpWindow.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popUpWindow.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.35).isActive = true

message.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
message.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: POP_UP.SPACING_Y).isActive = true
message.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: POP_UP.EDGE_INSET).isActive = true
message.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -POP_UP.EDGE_INSET).isActive = true
message.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cancel.topAnchor, constant: -POP_UP.SPACING_Y).isActive = true

cancel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cancel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: message.bottomAnchor, constant: POP_UP.SPACING_Y).isActive = true
cancel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: POP_UP.EDGE_INSET).isActive = true
cancel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -POP_UP.EDGE_INSET).isActive = true

ok.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
ok.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: message.bottomAnchor, constant: POP_UP.SPACING_Y).isActive = true
ok.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -POP_UP.EDGE_INSET).isActive = true
ok.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cancel.rightAnchor, constant: POP_UP.SPACING_X).isActive = true
ok.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cancel.heightAnchor).isActive = true
ok.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cancel.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

**UPDATE:**
I noticed there was a mismatch between my preferred width and my left and right constraint anchors which may have been causing the height to be calculated shorter than it should have been.

here are the updates I made in case anyone is having the same issue:

changed preferred width:

```
message.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = frame.width * 0.5
```

removed left and right anchor constraints and added width constraint making sure it has the exact same value as preferredMaxLayoutWidth:

```
message.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * 0.5).isActive = true
message.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Probably you should call layoutIfNeeded() as well.

Comment: @PavelKozlov i tried but unfortunately it did not fix the problem

Comment: what is the bottom constraint of the `cancel` view?

Comment: Updated question with all the constraints

Comment: update the cancel view bottom constraint from equalTo: to be greaterThanOrEqualTo: and fix the function accordingly

Comment: Tried it. But unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this in code? It seems like a lot of extra work when you could do it in interface builder and get the same functionality without having to manually set all the constraints. That'll change with SwiftUI, but for now, IB's a lot simpler route to go.

Comment: show full popup UI so we can try to figure out the issue .

Comment: @Adrian I find that once you're used to it its not that much harder to do the views programmatically. For the most part it is much cleaner and easier to debug and doesn't cause merge conflicts like the storyboard when working with others.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I've already solved the problem. See update.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting constraints relative to the other views. If the other views has fixed height than I would not expect your UILabel's size to fit the text.
I would set the bottom and top constraints like this

```
message.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: POP_UP.SPACING_Y).isActive = true
message.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: cancel.topAnchor, constant: -POP_UP.SPACING_Y).isActive = true
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor/1500948-constraint

Comment: It will update the height up to a certain point but often cuts off the last line needed. See edit. I added an example of what I mean.

Comment: Can you also add popUpWindow.sizeToFit() and try again? also what are the constraints of the popUpWindow, is it fixed? Try changing its constraints to greaterThanOrEqualTo too.

Comment: Tried adding popUpWindow.sizeToFit() and changing constraints to greaterThanOrEqualTo. Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. The popUpWindow  only has a fixed constraint for the width.

Comment: Can you share the code of constraints of the other views? Specifically cancel and imageView

Comment: Updated question with all the constraints